# Play 2.1 Scala SQLException Connection Timed out waiting for a free available connection

Tags: scala, jdbc, playframework, playframework-2.0, h2

I have been working on this issue for quite a while now and I cannot find a solution...

A web app built with play framework 2.2.1 using h2 db (for dev) and a simple Model package.
I am trying to implement a REST JSON endpoint and the code works... but only once per server instance.

```
def createOtherModel() = Action(parse.json) {
  request =>
    request.body \ "name" match {
      case _: JsUndefined => BadRequest(Json.obj("error" -> true,
        "message" -> "Could not match name =(")).as("application/json")
      case name: JsValue =>
          request.body \ "value" match {
            case _: JsUndefined => BadRequest(Json.obj("error" -> true,
              "message" -> "Could not match value =(")).as("application/json")
            case value: JsValue =>
              // this breaks the secod time
              val session = ThinkingSession.dummy
              val json = Json.obj(
                  "content" -> value,
                  "thinkingSession" -> session.id,
                )
              )
              Ok(Json.obj("content" -> json)).as("application/json")
          }
        } else {
          BadRequest(Json.obj("error" -> true,
            "message" -> "Name was not content =(")).as("application/json")
        }
    }
}
```

so basically I read the JSON, echo the "value" value, create a model obj and send it's id.

the `ThinkingSession.dummy` function does this:

```
def all(): List[ThinkingSession] = {

// Tried explicitly closing connection, no difference
//val conn = DB.getConnection()
//try {
//  DB.withConnection { implicit conn =>
//    SQL("select * from thinking_session").as(ThinkingSession.DBParser *)
//  }
//} finally {
//  conn.close()
//}
  DB.withConnection { implicit conn =>
    SQL("select * from thinking_session").as(ThinkingSession.DBParser *)
  }
}

def dummy: ThinkingSession = {
  (all() head)
}
```

So this should do a `SELECT * FROM thinking_session`, create a model obj list from the result and return the first out of the list.

This works fine the first time after server start but the second time I get a

```
play.api.Application$$anon$1: Execution exception[[SQLException: Timed out waiting for a free available connection.]]
    at play.api.Application$class.handleError(Application.scala:293) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.2.1]
    at play.api.DefaultApplication.handleError(Application.scala:399) [play_2.10.jar:2.2.1]
    at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$applyOrElse$3.apply(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:261) [play_2.10.jar:2.2.1]
    at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$applyOrElse$3.apply(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:261) [play_2.10.jar:2.2.1]
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145) [scala-library.jar:na]
    at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$2.applyOrElse(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:261) [play_2.10.jar:2.2.1]
  Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Timed out waiting for a free available connection.
    at com.jolbox.bonecp.DefaultConnectionStrategy.getConnectionInternal(DefaultConnectionStrategy.java:88) ~[bonecp.jar:na]
    at com.jolbox.bonecp.AbstractConnectionStrategy.getConnection(AbstractConnectionStrategy.java:90) ~[bonecp.jar:na]
    at com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCP.getConnection(BoneCP.java:553) ~[bonecp.jar:na]
    at com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCPDataSource.getConnection(BoneCPDataSource.java:131) ~[bonecp.jar:na]
    at play.api.db.DBApi$class.getConnection(DB.scala:67) ~[play-jdbc_2.10.jar:2.2.1]
    at play.api.db.BoneCPApi.getConnection(DB.scala:276) ~[play-jdbc_2.10.jar:2.2.1]
```

My application.conf (db section)

```
db.default.driver=org.h2.Driver
db.default.url="jdbc:h2:file:database/[my_db]"
db.default.logStatements=true
db.default.idleConnectionTestPeriod=5 minutes
db.default.connectionTestStatement="SELECT 1"
db.default.maxConnectionAge=0
db.default.connectionTimeout=10000
```

Initially the only thing set in my config was the connection and the error occurred. I added all the other stuff while reading up on the issue on the web.

What is interesting is that when I use the h2 in memory db it works once after server start and after that it fails. when I use the h2 file system db it only works once, regardless of the server instances.

Can anyone give me some insight on this issue? Have found some stuff on bonecp problem and tried upgrading to 0.8.0-rc1 but nothing changed... I am at a loss =(

Answer (score -2, accepted):

turns out the error was quite somewhere else... it was a good ol' stack overflow... have not seen one in a long time. I tried down-voting my question but it's not possible^^

Comment: Hi NemoOudeis. can you please tell me how did you solved the issue.. Even I am facing same issue

Answer (score 0):

Try to set a maxConnectionAge and idle timeout

Comment: tried with maxConnectionAge=0 and 5 seconds and with idleTimeout=0 and bigger, but it does not change a thing =(